# Rsync - Splitt Folder / Subfolder structure

Tags: rsync, split

I use openmediavault (OMV is a NAS software from openmediavault.org) and have different shares defined. In one of the shares I have a folder structure like this: (examples)

```
Subfolder"ABC"/Subsubfolder"SWU"/*.*Files   
Subfolder"ABC"/Subsubfolder"SXY"/*.*Files
Subfolder"ABC"/Subsubfolder"ZWE"/*.*Files   
Subfolder"BCD"/Subsubfolder"SWU"/*.*Files
Subfolder"CDE"/Subsubfolder"ABC"/*.*Files   
Subfolder"TXY"/Subsubfolder"SWU"/*.*Files
```

and would like to divide this to two diverent shares via rsync from within OMV, but I have problems to get it working with include /exclude.
I have limited possibilities to make use from rsync, but have an extra options field in the OMV-Rsync gui to enter a include/exclude statement.
[image: OMV]

I would like to split it up at the Subfolders, I would like to have the Subfolders starting from "0" to "Sj" as one part an starting with "Sk" to "Z" the other.

I already tried

```
--exclude={/S[k-z]*/,/[T-z]*/}
```

but that doesn't work as desired. 
A dryrun showed me that for example files within the folder:
Zur/S056776/ were also synced
What can I do, to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

### Edited answer to match the edited question

You can try the following exclude pattern. Change directory to above the common folder and modify the pattern from `folder` to match your actual common folder name.

```
--exclude={/folder/S[k-z]*/,/folder/[T-z]*/}
```

I don't know why your attempted pattern does not work (but if you show exactly what directories do not work, I might be able to help you find the problem),

```
--exclude={/S[k-z]*/,/[T-z]*/}
```

### Edit 2,3 - the NAS server is running a linux operating system

The NAS server is running a linux operating system. I have downloaded openmediavault, OMV, and tested. It is running an `ssh` server and it is possible to run `rsync` both to transfer files between your computer and the server and to login remotely to the server via `ssh` and run `rsync` internally in the server.

- Login info unless you have changed it

> Web interface
>
> ```
> User: admin
> Password: openmediavault
> ```
>
> Client (SSH, console)
>
> ```
> User: root
> Password: <The password that you have set during installation>
> ```

- Open a terminal window and connect via `ssh`

  ```
  ssh root@ip-address-to-your-server
  # example: ssh root@192.168.0.10  # if local
  ```
- Log in or use key authentication to run `rsync` in the server
- Run commands in the server

  ```
  cd 'path-to-directory-above-folder'

  mkdir target1  # only once, or use a target above your current directory
  mkdir target2  #               -"-

  rsync -Havn --exclude={/target*/,/folder/S[k-z]*/,/folder/[T-z]*/} * target1
  rsync -Havn --exclude={/target*/,/folder/[0-R]*/,/folder/S[0-j]*/} * target2
  ```
- You can run some other commands to see that everything is fine, for example

  ```
  for i in $(find folder);do test -e "${i/folder/target1\/folder}" || test -e "${i/folder/target2\/folder}" || echo "$i not copied";done
  ```
- Log out from the server when done (in my case from the user `myself` and from `root`) with

  ```
  exit
  ```

  [image]

### Original answer

I am not sure, but I *think* the following command lines will create what you want.

In a test directory I created the subdirectories `target1`, `target2` and `folder`, and in `folder` several subdirectories and files for testing.

```
rsync -Havn --exclude={/target*/,/folder/S[k-z]*/,/folder/[T-z]*/} * target1

rsync -Havn --exclude={/target*/,/folder/[0-R]*/,/folder/S[0-j]*/} * target2
```

- First run them with the option `-n` (as they are here) 'dry run', to check what they will do,
- then, (maybe after modifications) when they do what you want, remove `-n` and let `rsync` copy the directory structure to the target directories.

I tested with the following directory tree:

```
$ find |sort
.
./folder
./folder/ABC
./folder/ABC/SWU
./folder/ABC/SWU/file
./folder/ABC/SXY
./folder/ABC/SXY/file
./folder/ABC/ZWE
./folder/ABC/ZWE/file
./folder/AIB
./folder/AIB/Sja
./folder/AIB/Sja/file
./folder/AIB/Skb
./folder/AIB/Skb/file
./folder/AIB/SWU
./folder/AIB/SWU/file
./folder/BCD
./folder/BCD/SWU
./folder/BCD/SWU/file
./folder/CDE
./folder/CDE/SWU
./folder/CDE/SWU/file
./folder/Sja
./folder/Sja/Skb
./folder/Sja/Skb/file
./folder/Sja/SWU
./folder/Sja/SWU/file
./folder/Skb
./folder/Skb/Sja
./folder/Skb/Sja/file
./folder/Skb/SWU
./folder/Skb/SWU/file
./folder/TXX
./folder/TXX/Sja
./folder/TXX/Sja/file
./folder/TXX/Sjb
./folder/TXX/Sjb/file
./folder/TXX/Skb
./folder/TXX/Skb/file
./folder/TXY
./folder/TXY/SWU
./folder/TXY/SWU/file
./folder/Zab
./folder/Zab/ABC
./folder/Zab/ABC/file
./folder/zBC
./folder/zBC/ABC
./folder/zBC/ABC/file
./folder/zBC/ABC/target
./folder/zBC/target
./target1
./target2
```

with the following 'dry runs'

```
$ rsync -Havn --exclude={/target*/,/folder/S[k-z]*/,/folder/[T-z]*/} * target1
sending incremental file list
folder/
folder/ABC/
folder/ABC/SWU/
folder/ABC/SWU/file
folder/ABC/SXY/
folder/ABC/SXY/file
folder/ABC/ZWE/
folder/ABC/ZWE/file
folder/AIB/
folder/AIB/SWU/
folder/AIB/SWU/file
folder/AIB/Sja/
folder/AIB/Sja/file
folder/AIB/Skb/
folder/AIB/Skb/file
folder/BCD/
folder/BCD/SWU/
folder/BCD/SWU/file
folder/CDE/
folder/CDE/SWU/
folder/CDE/SWU/file
folder/Sja/
folder/Sja/SWU/
folder/Sja/SWU/file
folder/Sja/Skb/
folder/Sja/Skb/file

sent 742 bytes  received 106 bytes  1,696.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

and

```
$ rsync -Havn --exclude={/target*/,/folder/[0-R]*/,/folder/S[0-j]*/} * target2
sending incremental file list
folder/
folder/Skb/
folder/Skb/SWU/
folder/Skb/SWU/file
folder/Skb/Sja/
folder/Skb/Sja/file
folder/TXX/
folder/TXX/Sja/
folder/TXX/Sja/file
folder/TXX/Sjb/
folder/TXX/Sjb/file
folder/TXX/Skb/
folder/TXX/Skb/file
folder/TXY/
folder/TXY/SWU/
folder/TXY/SWU/file
folder/Zab/
folder/Zab/ABC/
folder/Zab/ABC/file
folder/zBC/
folder/zBC/ABC/
folder/zBC/ABC/file
folder/zBC/ABC/target/
folder/zBC/target/

sent 713 bytes  received 100 bytes  1,626.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great. I tried it without the starting folder, and I think I cant make use of "target" cause of using rsync from within Openmediavault so I tried with: ´--exclude={/S[k-z]*/,/[T-z]*/}´ and that doesn't work, cause subfolder matched the pattern.

Comment: @rsyncbeginner, Please describe the directory tree, seen when you are in the folder, where you want to run your command line. You can run `find |sort` or if there is too much output `find -maxdepth 2 |sort` and edit your original question to show the result. Indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as 'code'. -- I don't know Openmediavault. Please describe it.

Comment: Thanks for you help! I tried my very best to describe my problem better!

Comment: @rsyncbeginner, 1. I edited the answer. Please try again with the exclude pattern that I suggested if you can change directory (or change the directory structure to get above the common folder `folder`). 2. Is the NAS server running a linux operating system? In that case, I would guess it is running some `ssh` server and it should be possible to run `rsync` both to transfer files between your computer and the server and to login remotely to the server via `ssh` and run `rsync` internally in the server.

Comment: @rsyncbeginner, Congratulations, I'm glad that it works now :-)